# Как заблокировать клавишу в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В моей игре есть пауза, которая вызывается клавишей *"Esc"*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После поражения, всплывает слой поверх игры с надписью *"Game Over"*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как это слой,а не новая сцена, то пауза может работать в момент *Гейм Овера*.

**Вопрос:** как заблокировать *Esc* и затем его восстановить? Какой-нибудь *Enabled*?

***Скрипт LifeManager:***

```
void Update () {
        if (lifeCounter == 0) 
        {
            gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
            player.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        theText.text = "x " + lifeCounter;

        if (gameOverScreen.activeSelf)
        {
            //тут блокируем клавишу *"Esc"*.
            waitAfterGameOver -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(waitAfterGameOver < 0)
        {
            //тут разблокируем клавишу "Esc".
            Application.LoadLevel(mainMenu);
        }
    }
```

***Скрипт PauseMenu:***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public string levelSelect;

    public string mainMenu;

    public bool isPaused;

    public GameObject pauseMenuCanvas;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isPaused) {
            pauseMenuCanvas.SetActive (true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        } else {
            pauseMenuCanvas.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            isPaused = !isPaused;
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        isPaused = false;
    }

    public void  LevelSelect()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (levelSelect);
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (mainMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: ну вообще сааааааамый стандартный и примитивный механизм это флаг `isGameOver` , который делаете true/false когда нужно..... и соответственно где у вас обработка на клавишу `ESC` происходит пишите: `if (isGameOver) return;`  вот и все......

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Полезно, но такое себе...) Если что воспользуюсь вашим советом.

Comment: Думаете есть более лучший вариант?)) вам же нужно условие при котором ESC не работает... вот оно то самое условие.

Comment: А можете показать (добавить в вопрос) блок кода где обработка ESC идет? она в Update происходит ведь?

Comment: Нет, серьёзно, **что именно** мешает не обрабатывать нажатие, если игра окончена?

Comment: Разбей игру на состояния "Игра", "Пауза", "Конец игры" где состояние это функция которая вызывается в Update(какого то единствиного объекта к примеру StateController). В ней можно обрабатывать все нужние события клавитауры и тд. Прямой ответ на вопрос - заблокировать нельзя, но можно не обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вижу 2 пути:

1. Boolean isGameOver
2. в обработке где обрабатывается Esc проверять не Visible(Enabled?) ли гем овер скрин.

Но лучше boolean.