# Отключение иконки и клавиши Esc

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть персонаж, который в сцене №3 берёт предмет «рычаг» (необходимый в сцене №1), на котором висит скрипт «LeverUpSave».

```
    public class LeverUpSave : MonoBehaviour 
    {
    bool pickedUp;
    public GameObject TextLeverUp;   //иконка "рычага"


    void Start()
    {
        if (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == true)
        {
            TextLeverUp.SetActive (true);       
        }
        else
        {
            TextLeverUp.SetActive (false);          
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            pickedUp = true;
            SaveSystem.SetBool("bool", pickedUp);
            AudioManager.Instance.PlayAudio("Key_Lever");
            TextLeverUp.SetActive (true);           
            Destroy(gameObject, 0.5f);            
        }
       }      
      }
```

В следствии чего активируется иконка «рычага», данное событие сохраняется, и префаб «рычага» уничтожается. В сценах №1-2 также есть иконки «рычага» и «менеджер рычага»)) со скриптом «LeverTextGO»,

```
public class LeverTextGO : MonoBehaviour 
{
bool pickedUp;
bool turnOn;    
public GameObject TextLeverUp;  

void Start()   
{
    if ((turnOn = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == true) || (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == false))
    {
        TextLeverUp.SetActive (false);
    }
    if (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == true)
    {
        TextLeverUp.SetActive (true);       
    }
   }
  }
```

благодаря которому, если персонаж взял рычаг, то иконка активна, а после того, как донёс до места и положил куда надо – должна отключаться. В сцене №1 есть триггер (точнее два, первый активирует надпись, что тут, мол, нужен «рычаг») со скриптом «LeverTurnOn»

```
    public class LeverTurnOn : MonoBehaviour 
    {

    bool pickedUp;
    bool turnOn;
    bool isGameOver;
    public GameObject TextKeyUp; // иконка рычага
    public GameObject TriggTextLever;  // старое сообщение на UI о рычаге
    public GameObject TriggLever;  // старый триггер на рычаге
    public GameObject Lever_GO;  // старый агрегат "рычаг"
    public GameObject LeverN_GO;  // новый агрегат "рычаг"
    public GameObject PanelFin;  // панель на UI о завершении игры
    public GameObject PausePenel;


    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == true)
            {
                AudioManager.Instance.PlayAudio("Key_Lever");
                TextKeyUp.SetActive (false);
                TriggLever.SetActive (false);
                Lever_GO.SetActive(false);
                TriggTextLever.SetActive (false);               

                LeverN_GO.SetActive (true);
                turnOn = true;
                pickedUp = false;
                SaveSystem.SetBool("bool", turnOn);
                SaveSystem.SaveToDisk();
                Debug.Log("Save leverUp to disk.");
            }
            if (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == false)
            {
                Lever_GO.SetActive(true);
                TriggTextLever.SetActive(true);
                LeverN_GO.SetActive(false);
            }           
        }
    }

        void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                if (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == true)
                {
                    PausePenel.SetActive(false);
                    PanelFin.SetActive (true);
                    isGameOver = true;
                    Cursor.visible = true;
                    Time.timeScale = 0;
                    AudioManager.Instance.PlayAudio("PanelFinSound");               
                }
                if (pickedUp = SaveSystem.GetBool("bool") == false)
                {
                    PanelFin.SetActive (false);
                }    
              }
            }     
          }
```

- который отключает первый триггер, отключает иконку, активирует принесённый рычаг, сохраняет это событие, а на выходе из триггера – активирует UI панель «PanelFin», с кнопками «Quit» и «Menu». 
  Первая проблема в том, что, если перезайти в сцену 1 или 2, то иконка «рычага» опять активна – но я уже положил рычаг на место и она должна появиться (по задумке), только если я снова возьму рычаг в сцене №3. 
  А вторая проблема в том, что я не знаю, как правильно отключить кнопку Esc (которой управляет скрипт «SumPause»), на момент активации панели «PanelFin» с кнопками «Quit» и «Menu».

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.UI;

  [RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
  /// <summary>Singleton class for controlling pause functions.</summary>
  public class SumPause : MonoBehaviour {

  // Event managers
  public delegate void PauseAction(bool paused);
  public static event PauseAction pauseEvent;
  public bool isGameOver;

  // Variables set via inspector
  [SerializeField]
  bool useEvent = false, detectEscapeKey = true;
  [SerializeField]
  Sprite pausedSprite, playingSprite;

  // Link to button's image
  Image image;

  static bool status = false;
  /// <summary>
  /// Sets/Returns current pause state (true for paused, false for normal)
  /// </summary>
  public static bool Status {
      get { return status; }
      set {
          status = value;
          Debug.Log("Pause status set to " + status.ToString());

          OnChange();

          // Change image to the proper sprite if everything is set
          if (CheckLinks())
              instance.image.sprite = status ? instance.pausedSprite : instance.playingSprite;
          else
              Debug.LogError("Links missing on SumPause component. Please check the sumPauseButton object for missing references.");

          // Notify other objects of change
          if (instance.useEvent && pauseEvent != null)
              pauseEvent(status);               
      }
  }

  // Instance used for singleton
  public static SumPause instance;

  void Awake ()
  {
      image = GetComponent<Image>();
  }

  void Start () 
  {        
      // Ensure singleton
      if (SumPause.instance == null)
          SumPause.instance = this;
      else
          Destroy(this);
  }

  void Update() 
  {
      // Listen for escape key and pause if needed
      if (detectEscapeKey && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
       TogglePause();           
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Flips the current pause status. Called from the attached button in 
  /// the inspector.
  /// </summary>
  public void TogglePause () 
  {
      Status = !Status; // Flip current status
  }

  /// <summary>Checks if all links are properly connected</summary>
  /// <returns>False means links are missing</returns>
  static bool CheckLinks () {
      return (instance.image != null && instance.playingSprite != null && instance.pausedSprite != null);
  }

  /// <summary>This is what we want to do when the game is paused or unpaused.</summary>
  static void OnChange() {
      if(status) {
          // What to do when paused
          Time.timeScale = 0; // Set game speed to 0
          Cursor.visible = true;
      }
      else {
          // What to do when unpaused
          Time.timeScale = 1; // Resume normal game speed
          Cursor.visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Возможно поможет с вашей проблемой по поводу блокировки клавиши.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621224/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83-%D0%B2-unity

Comment: Спасибо. Я видел этот пост. И даже пытался использовать.)) Если посмотрите скрипт SumPause, то найдете там "public bool isGameOver;" - но дальнейшие попытки использовать это - успехом не увенчались. Не хватает мне знаний.